# Grunt won't run even though installed globally and locally

Tags: gruntjs, npm

After following [these instructions](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) to allow installation of npm packages without sudo, I've run into some problems. Currently, I'm unable to run Grunt.

I've installed Grunt both locally and globally. But when I type `grunt` within my project, I get the following error:

`-bash: grunt: command not found`

When I check `npm list -g`, I get the following:

```
/Users/user1/.npm-packages/lib
├── grunt@0.4.5
├── grunt-cli@0.1.13
```

Grunt is also listed (grunt@0.4.5) when I use `npm list` in my local project.

My .bashrc file looks like this:

```
NPM_PACKAGES="/Users/user1/.npm-packages"
#export NODE_PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/lib/node_modules${NODE_PATH:+:$NODE_PATH}"
PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"
# Unset manpath so we can inherit from /etc/manpath via the `manpath`
# command
unset MANPATH  # delete if you already modified MANPATH elsewhere in your config
export MANPATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/share/man:$(manpath)"
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your `bin` directory set? This might be a helpful [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=98&v=JXi9pg5fsao&t=1m33s).  I made it start at the time where it talks about your `bin` folder.

Comment: What does your PATH look like? Try `echo $PATH`. You need to make sure `$HOME/.npm-packages/bin` is on your PATH (assuming that's where bins for global npm packages are installed).

Otherwise, have you tried an npm run script? Assuming you have added `grunt-cli` to your `devDependencies` (via `npm i --save-dev grunt-cli`), then add this to your package.json: `"scripts": { "check-grunt": "grunt --version" }` and try `npm run check-grunt` from your project directory. It should output something like `grunt-cli v0.1.13`.

Comment: @superEb When I tried `echo $PATH`, I got `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. When I added the script to the package file and ran `npm run check-grunt`, I got `sh: grunt: command not found`

Comment: @aug When I install a global package, I get this: `/Users/user1/.npm-packages/bin/jshint -> /Users/user1/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/jshint/bin/jshint`

Comment: @Ken npm is installing global node bins in `~/.npm-packages/bin` but that's not on your PATH - this is why bash can't find them. Did you `export PATH=$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH` in your `~/.bash_profile` file [as mentioned here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md#3-ensure-npm-will-find-installed-binaries-and-man-pages-add-the-following-to-your-bashrczshrc)?

For the npm run script to work, you need to make sure `grunt-cli` is listed in your `devDependencies` in package.json. Mind posting the contents of package.json for us?

Comment: @superEb I didn't have grunt-cli installed locally. Only globally. When I installed it locally in the project and ran `npm run check-grunt`, I got `grunt-cli v0.1.13
grunt v0.4.5`. I'll post my .bashrc file to my question above.

Comment: @Ken Try exporting your PATH reset (`export PATH="$NPM_PACKAGES/bin:$PATH"`) and then source your .bashrc file (`source ~/.bashrc`). That should get global bins working. You might want to consider just installing locally though and relying on npm run scripts to execute grunt. This has the advantage of not needing to install grunt globally in order to use it in your project. If other people will be working on this, all they have to do is clone your repository, `npm install`, and then `npm run whatever` to build it via local grunt.

Comment: @superEb That did the trick. If you'd like to convert this to an answer, I can mark it as the right answer.